# Recursive CTE SQL Query Help Needed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am using SQL Server 2012 and need to write a recursive SQL query to traverse back up the hierarchy (on the same table) to return a parent with a certain condition on its tuple.

I have setup this sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/990bc/3) with a recursive CTE but I am now in over my head.

What I need is to be able to return a fourth column (`ReportingLocationId int`) which is defined as the parent id up the hierarchy that has the `IsReportingRollup bit` set.

So for row 1 this would be null, and for rows 2, 3 and 4 this would be set as 2. Similarly for rows 5, 6, 7 this would be set as 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying your provided SQL Fiddle, I came up with:

```
WITH hierarchy AS (
  SELECT t.Id,
         t.Name,
         t.ParentId,
         CAST(NULL AS nvarchar(100)) AS parentname,
         case when t.IsReportingRollup = 1 then t.Id
              else null
         end as ReportingLocationId
    FROM Location t
   WHERE t.ParentId IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT x.Id,
         x.Name,
         x.ParentId,
         y.Name,
         case when y.ReportingLocationId is not null then y.ReportingLocationId
              when x.IsReportingRollup = 1 then x.Id
              else null
         end
    FROM Location x
    JOIN hierarchy y ON y.Id = x.ParentID)
SELECT s.Id,
       s.Name,
       s.parentname,
       s.ReportingLocationId
  FROM hierarchy s
```